# How can I add a class name to all the "%th"

Tags: html, css, sass, haml

I want to edit my table's row content (add padding etc).
If I place the class name in the "%tr", nothing happens. But when i place it in the "%th", it works. Of course I can't do that for every single one because I don't think that's good practise.
So what can I do to put all the "%th" in the same class without copy pasting it 15 times?

```html
%div{:style => "overflow-x:auto;"}
  %table{:class => "students_table", :border => "1"}
    %thead
      %tr
        %th{:class => "student_table2"} Registration Number
        %th Forename
        %th Surname
        %th Programme Code
        %th Deptcode
        %th Personaltutor
        %th Periodofstudy
        %th Access
        %th Contact
        %th Teaching
        %th Exams
        %th Practicals
        %th Circumstances
        %th Recommendations
        %th Last updated at
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why not put the class on the `tr` and target the `th` of that like `tr.class th { styles }` - or you can totally put a class on each `th`, that's not necessarily bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the direct children of tr and then apply your rules

```css
tr > th {
  color:red;
}
```